# SharePoint 2013 - Silverlight WebPart XAP Cache

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Good Morning,

I am new to sharepoint but I am pretty salty as far as silverlight goes. I know on a standard silverlight application hosted inside an ASP.NET app you can simply append .xap? here to make sure the xap files does not cache each time. In SharePoint I found only one article that even came close to exphttp://techblog.m-dd.com/index.php/2013/01/25/resolve-sharepoint-silverlight-webpart-caching-problem/. When I trying to Edit the WebPart and Under Application, provide path to .xap I click Configure. I then appent something like this to the end of the xap file: .xap?ver=1.1.1.0002 and recieve the following error in sharepoint: Cannot save all of the property settings for the Web Part. One or more errors have occured.

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've had a lot more luck by using a Content Editor Web Part and then embedding the  tag which then links to the .xap file from there. Essentially you can edit the HTML source of the page by adding such a web part.

In the Content Editor Web Part, select "Edit Source" and paste something similar to this:

```
<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="/Library/YourSilverlight.xap?v=1"/>
</object>
```

- See embedding Silverlight here: http://tz.nu/1o9pkSk
- See more about adding the Content Editor Web Part here: http://tz.nu/1tSCOnJ

Using this approach, you can simply modify the page and edit the CEWP (Content Editor Web Part) and append the querystring behind the .xap to something unique (in my case, perhaps increment it to YourSilverlight.xap?v=2).

As an alternative to all of the above; 
I've oftentimes developed my own base web part which hosts Silverlight .xap files, then I'll deploy and add that Web Part instead. I've often built-in the functionality for updated versions into the code so you never have to do that manually, but that's another story.